# Ruby/Chef include_recipe and know variables from parent file?

Tags: chef, ruby, chef-solo

I am trying to use a local variable in an included file. I get the error that's it's not defined. I am not sure a way to do this, do you? I have a recipe folder with:

```
recipes/
    development.rb
    testing.rb
    config.rb
```

**development.rb**

```
username = "vagrant"
static = []
django = ["project1", "project2"]

include_recipe "server::config"   # <-- Trying to use static and django in there.
```

**config.rb**

```
static.each do |vhost|  #  <-- How do I get the "static" var in here?
    ...
end

django.each do |vhost|  #  <-- How do I get the "django" var in here?
    ...
end
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't share variables between recipes, but there are two ways to share data between recipes.

1. The preferred route would be to externalize `static` and `django` as attributes in `attributes/default.rb`. This means they'll become available on the `node` object and accessible from each recipe.

**attributes/default.rb**

```
default["server"]["static"] = []
default["server"]["django] = ["project1", "project2"]
```

**recipes/config.rb**

```
node["server"]["static"].each do |vhost|
  ...
end

node["server"]["django"].each do |vhost|
  ...
end
```

2. Use [Chef libraries](http://docs.chef.io/libraries.html) to make a common method that returns these arrays.

My suggestion is to definitely stick with option one, it's the most common approach. Hope that helps!

Comment: You are the man!!!!!!!!

Comment: Glad to help :)

Answer (score 3):

A bit late to the party on this one, and I think the accepted solution is the preferred option here, but...

It is possible to set a variable in a 'parent' recipe and have it used in an included recipe by modifying the node at converge e.g.

`node.default['django'] = ["project1", "project2"]`

I have done this in the past where I want a helper recipe to behave slightly differently when called from different 'parent' recipes i.e. installing a different git repo, based on a accessing a slightly different set of config from the attributes.

As to whether this is best practise, I welcome comments, but it seemed easier than writing a resource to wrap the git lwrp.